I'm facing a authentication problem with Gitlab Ci pipeline while deploying the Ansible playbook
I've added the public key in the remote node where the installation has to be done. The SSH private key value is added in gitlab as variable file, runner is setup, even though getting this error:
<ansible@[MASKED]> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/home/gitlab-runner/builds/ZSxgtfmp/0/riyaz/ansible.tmp/SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ansible"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ControlPath="/home/gitlab-runner/.ansible/cp/f7c4351094"' ansible@[MASKED] '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ansible && sleep 0'"'"''
<ansible@[MASKED]> (255, b'', b'Load key "/home/gitlab-runner/builds/ZSxgtfmp/0/riyaz/ansible.tmp/SSH_PRIVATE_KEY": error in libcrypto\r\nansible@[MASKED]: Permission denied (publickey,password).\r\n')
fatal: [ansible@[MASKED]]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Load key \"/home/gitlab-runner/builds/ZSxgtfmp/0/riyaz/ansible.tmp/SSH_PRIVATE_KEY\": error in libcrypto\r\nansible@[MASKED]: Permission denied (publickey,password).",
    "unreachable": true
}
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
ansible@[MASKED]       : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1

Kindly guide me where things are going wrong and whats the solution for this connection error.
for reference the inventory.ini file is:
ansible@masked_ip_address

The error seems pretty clear that the key you are using is NOT accepted. More than that I don't know what anyone can say fromthe information you've provided.

Make sure that your public key is locked down so only you can read it (600), but "Permission denied" is what you need to troubleshoot. Have you used that key to SSH in yourself?
